# Mock a class, edit one method and use another

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, mockery

I am trying to test one method, which depends on the other. The first method registers a user but must check if the given username is available.

I tried something with test class

```
class Test {
    public function a() {
        return "ac";
    }

    public function b() {
        return $this->a();
    }
}
```

And I want to mock the class and edit behavoir of method "a".

I tried following

```
$m = new Test();

$mock = \Mockery::mock($m);
$mock->shouldReceive("a")
         ->andReturn("ad");

echo $mock->b();
```

But the method "a" stays unchanged.

How can I edit behavoir of the method "a" or, how do I do it elseway?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a test like this one :

```
public function testMethodB() 
{
    $test = \Mockery::mock('Test[a]');
    $test->shouldReceive('a')->andReturn('ad');

    assertEquals('ad', $test->b());
}
```

I think it works !